# appending zeroes to an integer variable in perl

Tags: perl

I have an integer value in perl, let's say $runid = 1, I need to create a new directory named R_00001 using `mkdir R_$runid` from the perl script. I am not able to append zeroes. "printf" does the trick for me when I print it but I am not able to figure out how to get this done. Please suggest some way.

Comment: [`sprintf`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#sprintf)

Comment: May I suggest you phrase this task as _prepending_ zeroes or perhaps "left padding" with zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf("R_%05d", $runid)
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always include an explanation on how this code works and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @BDL, There's no algorithm to explain here. The code works by calling `sprintf` to do exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote 2) One could add why `%05d` solves the problem and why sprintf is used instead of printf (which op suggested)

Comment: @BDL, "`%05d` pads to 5 spaces with zeroes because `%05d` pads to 5 spaces with zeroes"? /// The OP already knows what `printf` does.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the concatenate operator in a nested anonymous function:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $runid = 1 ;
mkdir (('R_0000' . $runid)) ;
```

Comment: Fails for numbers larger than 9.